# How to prove that a ordinary system of differential equations has n independent first integrals?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a proof exercise in which I  have to prove  how many first integrals there are in a ordinary system of differential equations.

In my attempt of the proof I have proven that an ordinary system of differential equation  has at most $n$ independent integrals, and that $n$ independent first integrals form an infinite number of  first integrals of the system. Now I only need to prove that there exits $n$ independent integrals (or first integrals) in an ordinary system of differential equation, and I don't know how to prove that. Sorry for my English, not a native English speaker.

Comment: What do you understand under "first integral"? The usual meaning is "constant of motion" such as energy, angular momentum,... In what sense are they "independent"? That there is no non-trivial linear combination of zero, or that there is no functional dependence? In what fashion do $n$ "first integrals" form an infinity of first integrals? What is the relation to solutions of the system?

Comment: Under first integral I mean the integral of the system of differential equations such that it is identically equal to a constant, and under independent I mean that there is no non-trivial linear combination of zero. Sorry for the confusion, I am learning mathematics in my native language, not English

Comment: There is a proof in the Arnold's book on ODE